# Cocoa Stop Button

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, macos, button

I load a file from the disk, chunk by chunk, and I would like to grant the user the opportunity to click on a button and stop loading. I already know how to do that with threads (e.g. detachDrawingThread) but here I wouldn't use that way. The loading method in facts should return a bool value, it's called from different points and it's usually followed by many other lines of code. So I can't launch the thread and leave it work in a separated thread. And I can't split my code so easily. It's really complicated.

I just need to detect if the user clicked on a given button. That's all.
Is a quick and simple way to do that without rewriting my whole app?

Comment: You definitely don't want to load the file on the main thread, because all of the UI events are handled on the main thread; so if you're busy reading from disk, there will be no way to respond to mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Your loading routine must be using some sort of loop. Create a boolean and in your loop test for the condition of the boolean. Then in your button selector, set the selector to change the status of the boolean. Once your loop goes around again, it will exit and stop loading data.

Answer (score 0):

First rule of good Mac apps:

### Don't block the main thread

Some options:

- Do the work on a background thread. Sounds like you don't want to/can't in this case
- Use something like `NSURLConnection` to process the data in small chunks on the main thread as it's read in, rather than running a continuous loop
- Run the event loop periodically while loading data so UI events can be processed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I usually use threads, but in this case in order to use a thread I should almost re-write my app... So I have found a quick solution. Within the loop I added:

while(event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask untilDate:[NSDate distantPast] inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode dequeue:YES]){
    [NSApp sendEvent:event];
        }
So when the user clicks on the button to stop the loop, I post a notification and exit the loop. It works well.